# How to specify classpath in executable java shebang file

Tags: java, java-11, shebang, java-shebang

I was trying to assess viability of using Java and libraries for scripting.
So I tried to get a java shebang file up and running while specifying a classpath.

## Environment

I have 2 scripts and a `jar` in my working directory:

```
user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ ls -l
total 144
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 136837 Apr 13 22:51 public-api-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user    256 Apr 13 22:52 test_with_cp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user    201 Apr 13 22:53 test_without_cp
```

The JVM is the following:

```
user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

## Working Case

The first script `test_without_cp` works as expected, the code is executed when running it with `./test_without_cp`:

```
user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ cat test_without_cp 
#!/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --source 11

public class HelloJavaScripts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Java scripts!");
    }

}

user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ ./test_without_cp 
Hello, Java scripts!
```

## Error Case

However, when I try to specify a `--class-path` then I get an error and the code is not executed:

```
user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ cat test_with_cp 
#!/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --class-path public-api-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar --source 11

public class HelloJavaScripts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Java scripts!");
    }

}

user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ ./test_with_cp 
Unrecognized option: --class-path public-api-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar --source 11
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

## Trial & Error

I am pretty sure that `--source` has to come last, but I tried to change the order of the arguments anyway:

```
user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ cat test_with_cp 
#!/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --source 11 --class-path public-api-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar

public class HelloJavaScripts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Java scripts!");
    }

}

user@host:/tmp/tmp.nhRfqSWEWt$ ./test_with_cp 
Error: Could not find or load main class ..test_with_cp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //test_with_cp
```

## Question

What is the correct way to specify the `--class-path` in a Java shebang file?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html

Comment: And the JEP: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: @homegrown I'm afraid Java 8 doc can't help me with a feature introduced with Java 11

Comment: @GustavoPassini Actually my question seems to be a duplicate :-/
The answer over there is not correct though.
Based on the other question I have investigated a bit further and I might be on the right track. Once I have the answer I will answer the other question.